# SQL, Select Max 5 From Field

Tags: sql, max

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 for a project of mine. It's a database project and I'm trying to do this:

I want to get 5 rows based on the 5 largest values in the field "percentage". Is It possible to do that with an SQL command?

Comment: Thanks for the comments I found the answer(Ryans Comment).

Comment: Remember to mark as answer if Ryan answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Select the percentage column, and order by it (desc). Then limit by 5.

```
SELECT percentage FROM x ORDER BY percentage DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 5 percentage_col1 FROM Table1
ORDER By percentage_col1 DESC;
```